# why float element works weird with negative margin?

Tags: css

The codes are as followed:

```css
 * {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
    }
.first {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.second {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

As the width of the first div is 100%, so there is no space for the second div in the first line and I thought the second div would be displayed in the next line, but the second div was disappeared. Then I found the offsetLeft value of the second div is -50% of the viewport, which was equal to the second div's own width.  So the second div was placed in the same line with the first div but its offsetLeft was negative so I couldn't see it. Why this is so weird when a float element with a  negative margin?

Comment: You need to clear the second div https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: @Gerard Thanks. I knew that clear would eliminate the effects of the first float div. But I just can’t figure out why the second div’s offsetLeft value would be negative if I don’t use clear.

Comment: I think the second div is not placed in the same line of first div. You negative left margin has removed the element from the document view. If you inspect and check the element position.

Comment: @Ashish I checked and I found the offsetTop values of the two divs are both 0. So I thought they were placed in the same line. And the second div’s offsetLeft value is negative and this is what I can’t understand.

Comment: Set second div to `width: 100%;`

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake Thanks. I tried and I found if the width of the second div is greater than the absolute value of its own margin-left value, the second div would be placed in the next line. But I still don’t know why the second div would be placed in the same line with the first div in the first situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With both boxes floated right the second box is placed on the *left of first box*:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                +-----++-------+|
|                                | red || black ||
|                                +-----++-------+|
|                                                |
```

With widths added on the boxes the second box is pushed on a new line:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|+----------------------------------------------+|
|| black                                        ||
|+----------------------------------------------+|
|                        +----------------------+|
|                        | red                  ||
|                        +----------------------+|
|                                                |
```

With negative left margin >= width added on second box the second box is placed next to first box:

```
                       +------------------------------------------------+
+----------------------++----------------------------------------------+|
| red                  || black                                        ||
+----------------------++----------------------------------------------+|
                       |                                                |
                       |                                                |
                       |                                                |
                       |                                                |
```

A rough explanation of this behavior is that when you add a negative margin equal to/greater than the width of the element, it apparent width becomes 0 and browser will fit it on the same line.

Comment: The [precise rules for floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#float-rules) rules 2 and 7 define this formally, but that text is somewhat mind bending to read.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks but I didn't find the negative margin value situation in the rules.

Comment: Thanks and the graphs are really helpful. But where can I find the last situation documented rule?

Comment: @T.T - the rules don't describe the negative margin, they describe the left and right outer edges, that is, the margin edges. When the negative margin equals the border box width, the margin box width is 0, the left and right margin edges are co-incident, and therefore can be placed on the same line as the first float without violating rule 7.

Comment: @T.T Sorry I wasn't able to find the details in the specs although the side effects of negative margins are mentioned (not explained) here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: @Alohci Now they all make sense to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The second div has `margin-left: 50%` and width of 50% which actually places it outside the screen. In that case there's no need for browser to move it down, it can place both divs in the same line according to your styling.

If you want both divs to float right and the second should take 50% of the screen, then just remove the margin-left.

```css
* {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
    }
.first {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.second {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**Clarification**

Why the second div is being placed outside?
The `float: right` rule make the div stick to the right side of the screen. and with the combination of `width:50%`, the most left point will be at the center of the screen. Then, when adding the `margin-left:50%` a margin with the size of 50% of the screen is added and most left point of the div will be placed at the right edge of the screen, so the whole div is actually outside the screen.

To make it even clearer look at this example:

I set the second div a `width:30%` and `margin-left:30%` and added a third div which also floats right with 30% width.

Now the browser can place both divs in the same line because the total width + margin is 90%.

```css
* {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
    }
.first {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.second {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.third {
  float: right;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

If we'll increase the margin-left to 45% then the total width will be 105% which forces the browser to move the third div to the next line

```css
* {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
    }
.first {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.second {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.third {
  float: right;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to figure out why negative margin would make the second div display in such way.

Comment: But why margin-left: -50% would place itself outside the screen?

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation with examples

Comment: but the second div is float right, so the margin-left is not supposed to affect itself, it should affect the next div.

Comment: Wrong, margin is related to the element itself